# Uniqueness of maximum of homogeneous functions

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose $f(x,y,z)$ is a positive differentiable homogeneous function of order $k$, i.e. $f(\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z)=\lambda^k f(x,y,z).$Moreover $f$ is not constant on $xyz=1$.

$\textbf{Q1.}$Does $f$ attain a $\textbf{unique}$ maximum on the surface $xyz=1$? (meaning if $f$ has a maximum at $(x,y,z)$ with $xyz=1$ and $f(x^*,y^*,z^*)=f(x,y,z)$ with $x^*y^*z^*=1$ then $(x,y,z)=(x^*,y^*,z^*)$)

$\textbf{Q2.}$ In addition to our assumptions, let $ f$ be also symmetric. Does it imply that the maximum of $f$ on $xyz=1$ is unique? $\textbf{unique}$ maximum on the surface $xyz=1$?

Comment: The function $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ is homogenous of order 3 and symmetric  but is constant on the surface.

Comment: You mean $f$ is not the zero function, but it may take the value zero? If it has a maximum or minimum this will be zero, because $k f(x,y,z)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}z$.

Comment: OK, so it can´t be a local maximum in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @copper.hat  Edited it.